Time derivative of flow of a non autonomous ODE
Edit: I'm gonna try to be more exhaustive
I'm an engineer and in one class my prof. briefly mentioned this result in his way to the solution of the multiple shooting method in the context of the CRTBP in orbital mechanics.
Let's consider the Circular restricted three body problem such that:
$
\dot{\underline x} = f(\underline x,t)
$
where:
$
\underline{x} = (\underline r,\underline v) = (x,y,z,v_x,v_y,v_z)$
and the dynamics of the CRTBP when normalized is:
$
\underline{\dot r} = \underline{ \dot v}
$
and
$
\dot {\underline v} = 
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\ddot{x} \\
\ddot{y} \\
\ddot{z}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 \dot{y} \\
-2 \dot{x} \\
0
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{l}
x \\
y \\
0
\end{array}\right)-\frac{(1-\mu)}{r_1{ }^3}\left(\begin{array}{c}
x+\mu \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right)-\frac{\mu}{r_2^2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
x+\mu-1 \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right)
$
In this context the state $\underline x$ at any instant t can be recovered through the flow $\phi$ of the ODE as:
$\underline x(t) = \phi(\underline x_0,t_0,t)$
Morevover by considering a linerization of the flow $\phi$ we can recover the State Transition Matrix $\Phi$ as:
$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \underline x_0}(\underline x_0,t_0,t) = \Phi(\underline x_0,t_0,t)$
such that:
$
\delta \underline x = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \underline x_0}(\underline x_0,t_0,t) \delta \underline x_0
$
Given this context and knowing that $x_i$ and $t_i$ are optimization variables of the problem where there are N $t_i$ instant in equally spaced grid such that:
$
t_i = \frac{t_1(N-i) + t_N(i-1)}{N-1}
$
given the constraint $z_i:= \phi(\underline x_i,t_i,t_{i+1}) -x_{i+1} =0$
Its partial derivative with respect to $t_1$ is:
$
\frac{\partial z_i}{\partial t_1} = \frac{\partial(\phi(\underline{x_i},t_i,t_{i+1})-\underline {x_{i+1}}))}{\partial{t_i}} = \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{t_i}} \frac{\partial{t_i}}{\partial{t_1}}+
\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{t_{i+1}}} \frac{\partial{t_{i+1}}}{\partial{t_1}} =
$
$
= -\Phi\left(t_i, t_{i+1}\right) \underline{f}\left(\underline{x}_i, t_i\right)\left(\frac{N-i}{N-1}\right)+\underline{f}\left(\phi\left(\underline{x}_i, t_i, t_{i+1}\right), t_{i+1}\right)\left(\frac{N-i+1}{N-1}\right)
$
Could anybody guide me through the the development of the $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{t_i}}$ and $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{t_{i+1}}}$ step by step. I understand that the derivative of $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ with respect to $t_1$ are zero because they are independent from $t_1$ as they are optimization variables but I don't understand the derivation of the terms $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{t_i}}$ and $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{t_{i+1}}}$
I'm sorry if the question is not properly stated but I probably miss some mathematical basis to properly state it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Any hint what $\underline{f}$ is?  Was it defined previously?  How are $\varphi$, $\phi$ and $\Phi$ related?

sorry Eric Towers I had abused the notation  $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are the same and  they are the flow of the ODE while $\Phi$ is the STM. $f$ is the dynamics I have now explicited it. I edited the question to make it more clear I hope it helps.
